# auto_increment jumps by 3 and not 1

Tags: mysql, debian, galera, mariasql, mariadb-10.5

I have noticed that in my mysql server, the auto_increment setting increments by 3, for example 3 6 9 12 15 etc.

All the tables in the database are having the same problem.

I'm using mariadb 10.5 on debian 10.

Could it be because of having a 3 vps galley cluster?

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 3     |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

Comment: Please demonstrate [Why should I provide an mcve for what seems to me to be a very simple sql query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Could it be because of having a 3 vps galley cluster?

Comment: Try something like `SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='the_table_you_want';` and tell us what are you getting?

Comment: 3838 this is the result

Comment: 3838 IS NOT divisible exactly by 3..

Comment: Try this query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%'` and tell the result? it will give 2 variable names and their values

Comment: MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 3     |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.002 sec)

Comment: @diaconuliviu Why is `auto_increment_increment` set to 3?

Comment: I have not changed anything in the MySQL settings.
I use these servers for an app that I am developing in php.

Comment: Could this be the reason?  https://galeracluster.com/library/kb/auto-increment-multiples.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They designed it to be like that. You could say that it is a limitation of using Galera. They made it like that to address the collision issue when generating sequential numbers as primary key during inserts in a Multi-Master cluster.

https://mariadb.org/auto-increments-in-galera/

Answer (score 2):

If you are actually using Galera, then `auto_increment_increment` needs to be 3 (or however many nodes (servers) are in the cluster).

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wsrep%';`

Comment: Yes, I use galera, then it is normal to be 3 in 3. And this does not affect that the id int255 ends 3 times faster than 1 in 1?

Comment: @diaconuliviu - What is int255?  If you mean `TINYINT UNSIGNED`, then yes, each node can insert about 85 rows before overflowing.  Take that into account when specifying datatypes.  Meanwhile `auto_increment_offset` should be 3 different values for the 3 nodes.  If you insert only into one node, then 85 rows is the limit.  If you insert in just the right way spread across 3 nodes, it won't overflow before about 255 rows.